# Draw quadratics with it crossing the x and y axis with points labled

Tags: r, plot, graph, grid, curve

I'm trying to draw curves and I need to have it crossing the x and y axis with where it crossing shown clearly on the graph.
Im using the code

```
curve(x^2-8*x+16, -2, 10)
```

this is making the curve I want but not showing the curve clearly crossing the axis

[image: picture of the graph from RStudio]

I have used Desmos to show what im aiming to create.

[image: Picture of the desired graph]

Comment: After plotting, `abline(h = 0, v = 0)`. And maybe also `grid()`.

Comment: And also `points(c(0,4), c(16,0), pch=16)`

Comment: At this point, now that you've been given hints in the comments and have not responded by amending your question, it appears to the rest of us that you are sitting back waiting for a complete solution to be handed to you. So, I'm now downvotoing for lack of effort. What would have been more responsive is to read the help pages for `abline` and `grid` and incorporate them into your question and state what else was needed and why it could not be found on efforts to use google and SO's searching facility.

Comment: I am sorry but i have been away the past day so havent been able to have a look at the problem until now.

Comment: Thank you for the comments however i need the points labelled as in the desmos screenshot ie (4,0). and i want the numbers on the axis like for desmos. i more or less want what desmos produces